# Reading a particular input from the txt file

Tags: c++, parsing

this is from the google practice problem, https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32014/dashboard#s=p1, and 
I'm just having a little bit of problem with reading the input. 
The input has the form

```
3
jam google foo code bar
20 15 40 30 60
foo bar
3 2
code jam
3 2
```

where the first integer is the number of cases, and each case consists of two lines. The first line contains the list of products, space separated, and second line contains your initial guesses for each product in the list, respectively.

For each case, I want to get the first line as a vector of strings, and second line as a 
vector of integers, and the code I came up with is the following: (made modifications using the comment)

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("B-small-practice.in");
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("B-small-practice.out");
inFile >> numCase;
inFile.ignore();
for (i = 0; i < numCase; i++) {
    vector<string> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    getline(inFile, a);
    getline(inFile, b);
    stringstream aa(a);
    stringstream bb(b);
    j = 0;
    while (aa >> c) {
        v1.push_back(c);
        if (aa.peek() == ' ')
            aa.ignore();
        j++;
    }
    while (bb >> d) {
        v2.push_back(d);
        if (bb.peek() == ' ')
            bb.ignore();
    }
}
```

(all the variables are defined)

However, this code terminates after throwing an error "out of range," and I'm not sure because I thought my code was within the range.

Is there a way of fixing this? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Try doing a `inFile.ignore()` after `inFile>>numCase;`.

Comment: @user2030677  that still doesn't fix the "our of range" error, but thanks. I voted yours as a useful comment.

Comment: Move `v1` and `v2` outside of the `for`. You also don't need to check for whitespace, the stream does that automatically.

Comment: Moreover don't update your code based on answers or comments. This will confuse newcomers to your question.

Comment: @0x499602D2 moving those outside of the loop doesn't fix anything. I do need to check for whitespace because otherwise, getline will take the entire line as a string, but what I want is not one long string (ex: jam google foo code bar), but a vector of strings (ex:a vector of length 5 such that vec.at(0)=jam, vec.at(1)=google, and so on )

Comment: What are you doing outside of this code?

Comment: @0x499602D2 nothing much besides declaring the variables. As I stated in the question, all the variables used in that code segment are defined. The problem lies in this code segment, and that's why I only put it here.

Comment: Are you actually accessing the vectors using `at()` anywhere else? Because that function throws the `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: @0x499602D2  no. I'm not. but I just kept doing compile&run for a while, and it works now for some reason.. (no code change). This is very strange...

Comment: Can you please post the full code [here](http://ideone.com) so I may run it.

Comment: @0x499602D2  yes, I can. I just posted it. it works fine on my pc now. Mine's on C++ btw, so it causes compilation error, and you also need to download the files from the google code jam links.